# Does customtkinter CTkButton hover has event option?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I want to perform an action when a mouse hover event occurred on customtkinter ctkbutton hover. is it yet implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the `CTkButton` [source code](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/widgets/ctk_button.py), the `on_enter` method is bound to the `<Enter>` event. This method is predominantly focused on updating the button's appearance on hover. If you want to trigger an additional callback on hover, you'll have to add another binding to the button

```Python
def on_enter(event):
    # put whatever you want to do 'on hover' into this function
    print('Button hovered!')


def on_leave(event):
    print(event)  # do something here


button = CTkButton(parent, text='Button!')
# use '+' to avoid overwriting the existing binding
button.bind('<Enter>', on_enter, add='+')
# you may also want to bind to '<Leave>' to complete the hover handler
button.bind("<Leave>", on_leave, add='+')
button.pack()
```

Comment: To properly manage a hover you also need to manage the leaving tag as well.